# How to handle TimeoutError in the context of a Playwright Test page helper?

Tags: typescript, playwright-test

The test is failing with:

```
     TimeoutError: locator.fill: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
     =========================== logs ===========================
     waiting for locator('[aria-label="Enter email address"]')
     ============================================================
 
        at ../poms/PaidProject/Invoice.ts:124
 
       122 |
       123 |   public async setClientEmail(email: string) {
     > 124 |     await this.#locators.clientInput.fill(email);
           |                                      ^
       125 |   }
       126 |
       127 |   public async editClient() {
```

Meanwhile, the page is created by extending Playwright test instance using `test.extend({clientPage})` where `clientPage` is ~

```
async (
  { browser: playwrightBrowser },
  use,
  testInfo: TestInfo,
) => {
  const browser: Browser = playwrightBrowser;

  const page = await createPage(browser, testInfo);

  // We only do this to allow the individual tests to execute commands that expect page context.
  // Without this we would need to essentially add this to the beginning of every test.
  await page.goto('/');

  await page
    .context()
    .tracing.start({ screenshots: true, snapshots: true, sources: true });

  try {
    await use(page);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('page threw an error', error);
  }

  const tracePath = `${testInfo.outputDir}/${testUid}.zip`;

  await page.context().tracing.stop({
    path: tracePath,
  });

  // upload trace...
};
```

I would expect Timeout to appear in the `page threw an error` code block, but it does not.

Where am I supposed to handle it?